# GCP doesn't allow packet with spoofed IP address - why?

Tags: networking, scapy, google-cloud-networking

I have problem because I want to send a packet generated by myself to my vm instance on GCP. I'm using following code with spoofed source address:

```
packet = IP(src="77.7.7.7", dst="MY-VM-IP")/UDP(sport=RandShort(), dport=53)/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="google.com"))

import time
while True:

  send(packet)
  time.sleep(1)
```

Although when I'm not changing source IP, I can see my packet with TCP dump on my VM.
How can I make it works? I have IP forwarding enabled on my VM and FW set to allow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [1](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#canipforward), it is possible as long as the VM who sends the packet has `IP forwarding` set to `ON`.

You also need to make sure that the VM who is recving the traffic has an Ingress FW rule that allows that.

I just tested the following and it worked:

- Created a VM A1, with allow everything from everywhere FW rule.
- Created another VM, B1 with IP forwarding enabled.
- Run the code above to generate and send a packet from B1 to A1.
- I could see with tcpdump the packet arriving on A1.

Comment: Sure, when you are in VPC that works. But I was sending this packet from my computer with IP from my ISP and it didn't.

Comment: I believe that packet is discarded from your ISP, or even earlier, from your router.

You can verify this by running a tcpdump on GCE VM, do you see any traffic coming?

If traffic is received on the external IP of a VM it is only dropped if a firewall rule is dropping it.